# Will DC with a frequency have reactance?

Tags: ac, dc, frequency, reactance

[image]

I am getting mixed answers for the question.

Quora says:

> There is no reactance! Xc = 1/(2 x pi x f x C), and since f=0, Xc = 0.

The frequency is *non-zero* (for second and third picture,) though.

Then I asked my teacher, he said that it does have a reactance.

I think that the capacitor should allow periodic or variable DC to pass and an inductor should not because it is continuously changing.

Comment: If you define "DC" as being a signal that is always positive or negative (i.e. "current flows only in one direction"), then sure, 1 2 and 3 are all DC. However, 2 and 3 are clearly varying, and therefore have non-zero frequency components. I suspect this comes from a difference in definition, since many people define "DC" as a constant voltage

Comment: Reactance is not a property of a signal. It is a property of a network of resistors, capacitors and inductors. You can possibly detect the reactance by exciting the network with a signal. I am just trying to clarify some terminology. A network with reactance always has it, even if it is not excited, or excited by DC.

Comment: `Xc = 1/(2 x pi x f x C), and since f=0, Xc = 0` - think again.

Comment: @Andy If f = 0, Xc is infinite!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All signals are a sum of AC and DC components. If AC component is 0, it's pure DC (flat fixed voltage). If DC component is 0, it's an AC. So yes, if there is changing always positive voltage, that's AC component right there, and it will behave as such with other components, including capacitors.

"Always positive" and "DC" is not the same, although in some contexts they're sometimes used interchangeably. Which is not entirely accurate. After all, voltage is relative, and you can set 0V to any level.

So what your "periodic DC" picture actually is, is an AC with DC offset.

Comment: So a capacitor should allow it to pass, right?

Comment: Technically one definition of "DC" is "a system where current flows in only one direction", so by this definition, 1 2 and 3 would be "DC". The fact that 0V can be arbitrarily defined doesnt actually invalidate this definition, since it's based on current flow (I dont actually agree with this definition of DC, but it is a real one, with much discussion on the wiki talk https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Direct_current)

Comment: @ExtroMechanic no capacitor "just passes AC". But yes, AC component will definitely behave like an AC with it

Comment: @BeB00 that is also true, exactly where problem with definition comes. Except it doesn't change the fact that "Variable DC" (positive, but changing) has an AC component

Comment: @BeB00 Well if you take the above "Periodic DC" signal and connect it to a capacitor, rising voltage will charge the capacitor and falling voltage will discharge the capacitor so clearly the current does not only go to one direction so even by that logic it is AC.

Answer (score 3):

If the voltage has changes then it's not DC. DC does not have changes as frequency is zero, AC does have a frequency since it changes.

So if a signal changes it clearly has an AC component, which may have an added DC component, and for completeness sake the DC component can be zero or non-zero.

Whether you call a varying DC voltage as "periodic DC" or "variable DC" is subject to an argument about terminology but it does not remove the fact that those signals have an AC component.

Answer (score 1):

The well-known capacitive and inductive reactance formulas are defined for steady-state sine-wave input signal because reactance and impedance concepts apply to sinusoids.

But if you can write the input with sum of sine waves (remember the Fourier series) then you can use the same formula for each frequency components and then combine them.

You can't describe the first one with sinusoids i.e. the Fourier series of a pure DC consists of only one term: the DC value. So there's no reactance.

But sure there's reactance for the others.